# Cypress maintain context

Tags: cypress

We have a platform with a lots of workflows and a lots of tests. Right now for each test we have to complete a long workflow. In order to speed up this, I want to share the context or the browser, with all the cookies, the url, and all the data between all the it inside each describe.

I could also crete just one it and put everything inside but i'll prefer to maintain all the it functions to have all more organizated.

I know that i'm dealing with anti patterns.. but this will improve significantly the speed of the tests.

So.. is there a way to acomplish this? I can't find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cy.session()` should get you most of the way there.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) It allows you create a `session`, from which Cypress will cache most of the browser context. The next time Cypress encounters the session command, it will check to see if it has created a session with the same id, and if it has, it will use those cached values. Otherwise, it executes the contents of the `cy.session()` command.

From the docs:

> Cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage (i.e. session data) in order to recreate a consistent browser context between tests.

> Once created, a session for a given id is cached for the duration of the spec file. You can't modify a stored session after it has been cached, but you can always create a new session with a different id.
> In order to reduce development time, when running Cypress in "open" mode, sessions will be cached for spec file reruns. To persist a session across multiple specs, use the option `cacheAcrossSpecs=true`

And their example using `cy.session` inside of a login command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  cy.session([username, password], () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(username)
    cy.get('[data-test=password]').type(password)
    cy.get('form').contains('Log In').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/login-successful')
  })
})
```